# Add an index to a dataframe. Pyspark 2.4.4

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

There are a lot of examples that all give the same basic example.

```
dfWithIndex = df.withColumn('f_index', \ 
  pyspark.sql.functions.lit(1).cast(pyspark.sql.types.LongType()))
rdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda row, rowId: (list(row) + [rowId + 1]))
dfIndexed = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=dfWithIndex.schema)
```

Really new to working with these lambdas, but printScema-ing that rdd with a plain zipEithIndex() gave me a two column dataframe.. _1 (struct) and a _2 long for the index itself.  That's what the lambda appears to be referencing.  However I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rowId'
```

Comment: When doing the plain rdd.show(), I get incrementing integers in _2 as expected, so that's good.  I'm just trying to get the dataframe back into it's normal columned state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You just need to modify the lambda function slightly. It should take in 1 argument, which is like (Row, id), and return a single Row object.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, LongType

df = spark.createDataFrame([['a'],['b'],['c']],['val'])
df2 = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(
    lambda r: Row(*r[0], r[1])
).toDF(df.schema.add(StructField('id', LongType(), False)))

df2.show()
+---+---+
|val| id|
+---+---+
|  a|  0|
|  b|  1|
|  c|  2|
+---+---+
```